# Input Hidden By Toolbar On Display of Mobile Keyboard

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, scroll

I have a popup that contains input fields. At the bottom of the popup is a toolbar with a confirm button. The popup is large enough on a mobile phone that it can be taller than the screen, causing the popup to be scroll-able. The toolbar footer should always be visible/accessible. Something like this:

```
/-----------\
^           ^
| scrolling |
| content   |
|           |
v           v
|-----------|
| footer w/ |
| submit btn|
\-----------/
```

On selecting a field on a mobile device, when the field takes focus and the phone's keyboard displays, the field with focus should scroll into view above the footer. Right now, however, it remains obscured by the footer.

Is there a way to change the behavior so that the field scrolls into view above the toolbar footer when the keyboard displays?

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'd prefer it if I could find a code-agnostic answer; I think I'm asking a more general question about managing scrolling when mobile keyboards display. Maybe my code is required, but I'd prefer a more general answer that doesn't take my particular code into account (if possible).